Amplify Flutter, key cannot be found when using downloadFile from S3: "The specified key does not exist"
I want non-authorized download from an S3 bucket. I've enabled all options for public access and ACL. After a adjusting the settings, I finally no longer got the access denied error. However, now I can't find any files. All the data I've uploaded, I did through the AWS web.
Bucket Policy:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<the bucket>/*"
    }
]}

Now I have a new problem. I can't find the files, I get this error:
NoSuchKeyThe specified key does not exist.public//100/gif1.gif (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: ***'),
Here's the code:
Future<void> downloadFromS3(String key) async {
  try {
    final localPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final filePath = '$localPath/$key';

    final result = await Amplify.Storage.downloadFile(
      key: "/100/$key",
      local: File(filePath),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error downloading file [$key] : $e');
  }
}

Then I run:
  await configureAmplify();
  await downloadFromS3('gif1.gif');

My bucket is structured like this: myBucket/100/gif1.gif.
I've been stuck on this for awhile now, the only thing I can assume is the problem is that in the error code you can see a public prefix "public//100/gif1.gif". Which I don't have, I've tried creating a folder "public" like this myBucket/public/folder100/file. However, that didn't really work either.
What's wrong?

It looks like the issue might be related to the key you're using to download the file. When you upload or list objects in an S3 bucket using Amplify, it often adds a prefix to the keys, such as "public", "private", or "protected", depending on the access level you specify during the upload. This could explain why you're seeing "public//100/gif1.gif" in the error message.
you might want to look into this stack question see this if it helps
How to stop aws-amplify from appending level and identityPoolId in the url while performing S3 operations
also verify the exact key of the file in your S3 bucket. You can do this by listing the objects in your bucket using the AWS S3 console or the AWS CLI.
